# Android adding and removing textviews in linearlayout programatically

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to add **views(TextView)** in linearlayout prgramatically. I am able to add textview in linearlayout programatically.

Here is my code to add textview:

```
public void setSelectedContactTextView(final ArrayList<Object> list){
        //Constants.progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(this, "", Constants.MSG_PROGESSDIALOG);
        /*  new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {*/
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(i<list.size()){
                    ContactBean contactBean=(ContactBean)list.get(i);
                    if(contactBean.isSelected()==true){
                        View line = new View(NewEventShowDetails.this);
                        line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        final TextView contactTextView=new TextView(NewEventShowDetails.this);
                        contactTextView.setText(contactBean.getEmailId().toString());
                        contactTextView.setPadding(3,3, 3, 3);
                        contactTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewEventShowDetails.this, contactTextView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        fbContactTextLinearLayout.addView(contactTextView);
                        fbContactTextLinearLayout.addView(line);
                        count++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });

        /*}
        });*/
    }
```

**I am calling setSelectedContactTextView() from OnResume() in activty. It adds textviews in activity first time but after calling removeAllTextViewsFromLayout() it won't add textviews again.**

Here is the code to remove textview:

```
public void removeAllTextViewsFromLayout(){
        final int childcount = fbContactTextLinearLayout.getChildCount();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                    fbContactTextLinearLayout.removeViewInLayout(fbContactTextLinearLayout.getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**This is defined in OnCreate()**

```
fbContactTextLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fbcontact_text_layout);
```

Comment: What about your removeViewInLayout(fbContactTextLinearLayout.getChildAt(i)); method code?

Comment: Why don't you just call `fbContactTextLinearLayout.removeAllViews();`

Comment: do you only call setSelectedContactTextView() from onResume()? When did You call this after removing views? If you only delete the views without doin anything else like leave the activity or pause or something like this, onResume won´t be called again.

Comment: @Neil I used that it will remove all textviews but after removing textviews Theses are not adding again.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Sorry but my onResume() will be called everytime.

Comment: try calling `fbContactTextLinearLayout.invalidate();` and then add your new views. Please also show the code where fbContactTextLinearLayout is defined

Comment: @Neil I have updated my code please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your i counter being reset? Based on the code you showed i is not a local variable.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(i<list.size()){
```

If you're not resetting i your loop will not run the second time (assuming the list hasn't had anything added to it).